# Exception handling in Symfony 2 Crawler

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I have this code

```
   try{

    $totalpages=$crawler->filter('.button-see-more');

        $totalpages=$totalpages->extract(array('data-total-pages'))[0];

        if($totalpages>0)
            for($i=1;$i<=$totalpages;$i++)
            {
                $client->request('GET', 'http://www.daraz.pk/catalog/getproducts/?pathInfo=phones%2Fqmobile&page='.$i.'&YII_CSRF_TOKEN='.$CSRF, array(), array(), array(
                    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
                ));
                echo $i.'th page: '.$client->getResponse()->getContent()."\r\n";
            }


}
catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

According to the doc pages

```
 $totalpages=$crawler->filter('.button-see-more');
```

when the filter doesn't match anytyhing it should throw an InvalidArgumentException which is not thrown, rather in the console I get

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in

How can I catch this?

Comment: PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ..........................???

Comment: @SimoneNigro in Crawler.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere in the documentation does it state that it throws an `InvalidArgumentException` if it doesn't match anything:

https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/2.6/Crawler.php#L675

The only exception that could be thrown is a `RuntimeException` if you haven't installed Symfony's CssSelector.  So in your case, the exception will never be thrown.

What you're instead looking for is the `count()` method (which is on the base [SplObjectStorage](http://php.net/SplObjectStorage) class.  So you could test if any are returned with:

```
if ($totalpages->count() > 0)
```

You could also just do

```
if ($totalpages->count())
```

Comment: So how should I deal with this if it doesn't match anything?